# image on image overlay (alt code)

Tags: image, overlay, alt

I have a problem... I have generated Youtube thumbnails and I want to add a "play button" with the alt code, which is the same as this one: ►

But, no matter what I do, this button won't show up.

PS: the problem is that it's a script, and I can't seem to add this button on the thumbnails. I made a class for the image, on which the button has to come but even then, the button didn't show up. Opacity and that kind of things are already done, the only thing I want is this button, but as said earlier, it won't work.

img.className = 'but' (this is the class I made in the script). The script is this one -->

http://www.yvoschaap.com/ytpage/ytembed.js

Answer (score 0):

Alt code image only appears when the image is not available.
It does not overlay the image.

Comment: Ah, I see... But how can I add a play button like this (or the same one) on the thumbnail? There has to be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css and div for this

```
#OverlayImage1
{
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
top: 20px;
width: 56px;
height: 45px;
background: url(underimage.jpg) no-repeat top left;
opacity: .80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
}

#OverlayImage2
{
position: absolute;
left: 40px;
top: 20px;
width: 56px;
height: 45px;
background: url(play.image) no-repeat top left;
opacity: .80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
}
```

also you can modify left:, top:, width:, and height: according to your images
hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/28vqfs2.png

This is what I get if I make a class of the image file (thumbnail) and put the elements of #Overlayimage2 in it...

The image I want to show isn't visible, but it's UNDER the thumbnail (as the site loads, I can see a glimp of it). So now is my question: how can I make the image visible and how can I make that for the other 3 thumbnails too?